# set column width in POI using BigGridDemo

Tags: java, excel, formatting, apache-poi

I am using BigGridDemo example for POI since I have to generate excel with a million records. However, I am unable to set the column width in the template.

https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/examples/BigGridDemo.java

I tried this:

```
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Big Grid");

//sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);
sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 13);
```

It somehow does not pick up the formatting from the template.xlsx

In case anyone is familiar with BigGridDemo, please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the BigGridDemo any more! As the name suggests, it was a demo of a possible way to handle low memory writing of big .xlsx files

Instead, you should be using [SXSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/#SXSSF+%28Since+POI+3.8+beta3%29). SXSSF implements the ideas of the BigGrid Demo, but provides the standard POI SpreadSheet interface to do so, and implements more of the format. You can see the [SXSSF section of the site](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/#SXSSF+%28Since+POI+3.8+beta3%29) for the current restrictions on what isn't supported.

Comment: But SXSSF does not support progressive write of workbook to the (servlet) output stream. It writes workbook at once via [workbook.write()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html#write(java.io.OutputStream)).

Comment: The BigGridDemo doesn't/didn't support progressive writing either. Not sure what you'd gain from it anyway - you need to wait until you've finished populating the sheets before you can finalise various references needed for a valid file

Comment: So there is no chance to write XLSX file row by row as CSV/Text file? I'm pointing to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3076312/3271406

Comment: Nope, if you want line-by-line, use CSV. Excel has back-and-forth references between bits of the file. You can generate parts of it in a streaming way, which is what SXSSF does, but the overall file can't be

Answer (score 0):

You should try a bigger number than 13. Try 5000 for example. See api reference for details
[setColumnWidth()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#setColumnWidth%28int)